# Get Request/Second in multi-pod spring application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, openshift, prometheus

I have **multiple** docker images (pod) of the same Spring-Boot application in a load-balanced environment (OpenShift) and each docker image exposes Prometheus endpoint. I have used the following query in Prometheus for getting requests/second of a single docker image:

`rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count [1m])`

The problem is that the query does not return a correct answer when Prometheus collect data from multiple pods (actually each time Prometheus call the application endpoint, one pod would be the target, because of the load-balancer).

Is there a way of getting the number of requests per second across all pods using Prometheus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I found the solution inside the OpenShift. You can define a scraper for each pod. But unfortunately, I can't remember the exact path to the solution, since I don't work on that project from a year ago.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like you pointed Prometheus at your loadbalancer rather than each of your instances separately. This will give you totally unusable metrics, as they will be randomly collected from one or another of your instances and there will be nothing in those metrics to tell you which instance it is coming from.

What you need to do is point Prometheus at each and every instance of your application. Prometheus will then collect metrics separately from each of them, applying an `instance` label with the IP address or DNS name of the instance it was collected from. I.e. you'll have N separate `http_server_requests_seconds_count` metrics:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="myapp",instance="1.2.3.4:8080"} 1234
http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="myapp",instance="5.6.7.8:8080"} 5678
...
```

If you then query Prometheus `rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m])`, you'll get a vector with separate values per instance:

```
{job="myapp",instance="1.2.3.4:8080"} 1.234
{job="myapp",instance="5.6.7.8:8080"} 5.678

...
```

If you want the total rate of requests per job, across instances, you can query instead for `sum by(job) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))`.

Comment: Thank you Alin. The IP of each instance may be changed every time restarted and we can't have a stable query (for example to be used in Grafana). The `instance` label have filled with the service address (e.g. https://example.com), not the instance address.

Comment: Prometheus supports an auto-discovery of pods and more in a  kubernetes environment. Here is a nice article in which you can find more detailed explanation: https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/monitoring-your-kubernetes-deployments-with-prometheus-5665eda54045